# Removing line-breaks, whitespaces and tabs from every file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, osx

Say I have a folder with 10K text files. I would like to remove every **space,** **TAB** and **linebreak** from each file.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: What do you mean by efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `tr`:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -d '[:blank:]\n' < file_in > file_out
```

Since when you have to work with 10k files, a better solution would be:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i.bak -pe 's/ |\t|\n//g' {} +
```

Comment: Why `[[:blank:]]\n` and not `[[:space:]]`?

Comment: @1_CR: `[:space:]` contains `[ \t\r\n\v\f]`, `[:blank:]` only contains `[ \t]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GNU `sed`:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob # includes "hidden" files beginning with .
$ sed -i.bak ':a;N;$!ba;s/[\n \t]//g' *
```

That will process all files in the folder. It stores a backup of the original file with extension `.bak`. Just use `-i` without `.bak`, if you don't want backups.

To do that recusively use that:

```
sed -i.bak ':a;N;$!ba;s/[\n \t]//g' $(find . -type f)
```

Comment: This will cause arguments too long error and only work with GNU sed.

Comment: Also won't work with filename contains spaces or newline characters. And GNU sed still leave the last newline untouch.

Answer (score 0):

Fromthe point of speed of handling the file contents, I would assume that `tr` is faster than a regexp solution in `perl`, `sed` or similar.

As for looping over ten thousand files, there's not much you can do, since `tr` will process `stdin` to `stdout`, so you're spawning `tr` 10k times any way you do it. For that, `find . -maxdepth -exec` is as good a way to go as any.

Comment: What you have written is a comment, not an answer.  Also, `-exec … {} +' means to run the command on as many files as possible in one batch (which perl accomodates)  vs. `-exec … {} \;' which means to run the command for each file; ie. many invocations.

Comment: Point well taken re multi-file arguments. However, I am not asking for clarifications or improvements to the OP's question, so this is rightfully not a comment. (For a lower-rep OP, I would possibly have gone back to provide more detail.)